# JComboBox: arrow-button should be shown at any time

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

If a `JComboBox` is not selected, the arrow-button on the right is not shown. This leads to the fact that a combo-box cannot be distinguished from a normal textfield.

The question is now: how is it possible to show the arrow-button permanently? I alrady came across `BasicComboBoxUI.createArrowButton()` etc., but I did not find out the mechanism of hiding / showing the arrow-button.

Can anyoune give me a hint how to show the arrow-button permanently ?

Comment: Have you checked [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)?

Comment: Can you show some code that illustrates this behavior?

Comment: There is nothing special you need to do. You have some strange coding problem and we can't guess what you are doing. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add below code as first line in your main method.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDesktopProperty("win.xpstyle.themeActive",Boolean.FALSE);
```

and then check your program.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the inconvenience. Everything is clear now. In have been told that we use a special framework which changes the behaviour. This information would have been useful if given to me earlier... :-(